# Does global variable always stays in memory..?

Tags: ios, swift

Here are some global constants and variables declared, so i want to know that whether thses types of initialized properties always stay in the memory?
Or are these the computed properties that every time i access them, a new instance is created and is lost as soon as its reference goes out of scope?

```
let storyboard                      =   UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let APPDELEGATE                     =   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var mainNavigationController        :   UINavigationController?
var slideMenuNavigationController   :   UINavigationController?
let clientIDInstagrm                =   "favf5"
var selectPhotoCount                =   0


//URL
let BASE_URL_FOR_ALBUM            = "http://admin.com/"
let BASE_URL                      = "http://admin.com"



//SIGN UP KEYS
let kNAME           =   "name"
let kEMAIL          =   "email"
let kPASS           =   "password"
let kAPP_KEY        =   "appkey"
let kDEVICE_TOKEN   =   "device_token"
let kDEVICE_TYPE    =   "device_type"
let kServiceMethod  =   "method"
let kSocialType     =   "social_type"
let kSocial_id      =   "social_id"
let kMethod         =   "method"

//KEYS RESPONSE
let kERROR_CODE     =   "error_code"
let kUSER_DETAIL    =   "User_details"
let kUSERNAME       =   "username"
let kIS_SELECTED    =   "SELECTED"

//BOOK PAGES KEYS
let kTEMPLATE_TYPE  =   "templateType"
let kIMAGE_1        =   "img1"
let kIMAGE_2        =   "img2"
let kIMAGE_3        =   "img3"
let kRightSidePage  =   "RightSidePage"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables always be in memory until they are released and works according to their scope whether they exists in some block or visible to entire class but in order to keep reference (new instance is created) here you need to understand **static** variable concept.

**static variable:** is a variable that is allocated for the entire lifetime of a program. `static` variable's value is maintained throughout all function/method calls. *When declared outside of a function, a static variable is visible to everything within the file in which it is declared, when declared inside a function or method, it is visible only within that function or method, but the value is retained between calls.*

Exapmle:

```
int method(void)
{
    int i = 5;
    i += 10;
    return i;
}
```

Here method return 15 everytime when call but if you make variable `i static` see below.

```
int method(void)
{
    static int i = 5;
    i += 10;
    return i;
}
```

Here everytime method calls it will return 15, 25, 35 so on because variable i retains its previous call reference.

**static** variable usage to control visibility of a variable in a translation unit. So, if you want to only allow some variable to be accessed within file, just like **C**, you can create them like:

```
static NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

this will probably raise memory leak.

**Edit:**

In order to decleare constant which are visible to whole app declare them as `extern` in the header and define them in the .m:

```
//.h
extern NSString *const yourVariableNameKey;

//.m
NSString *const yourVariableNameKey = @"some value";
```

Symbolic constant just like **c**:

```
// declare them where you write import statement 
// to access just import the class where you dec those variables and access by name

#define variable_1 @"string value"
#define variable_2 10  // int value
```

**Edit 2:**

In swift

```
struct Constants {
    static let someNotification = "TEST" 
}
```

Then call it like this in your code:

```
print(Constants.someNotification)
```

Comment: What is the right way to declare constant..?
I want to declare the constants that is visible in whole application but when i access  them they will get memory.

Comment: Yeah Thanks.
does it always stay in memory because of static..?

Comment: Yes salman but I suggest you to kindly clear your concept before use `static` it  may also effects memory management..

Comment: What do you mean by "clear your concept before use static..."?